# How to redirect port 8080 to port 443?

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy

I have an Apache 2 server and I installed NodeJS.

My site is already up and running https://www.mydomaine.com

If I use port 443 with NodeJS, it does not work. I saw that it was necessary to use ports from 1024.

How to redirect port 8080 to port 443?

I enabled proxy and proxy_http mods

Here is the configuration of my server :

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com .php
    Action php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com /php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com
    Alias /php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com -socket /run/php/php7.1-fpm.www.mydomaine.com.sock -idle-timeout 120 -pass-header Authorization

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 138.74.184.65:80 [2001:21d0:0305:2100:0000:0000:0000:4741]:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@mydomaine.com
    ServerName mydomaine.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomaine.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost 138.74.184.65:443 [2001:21d0:0305:2100:0000:0000:0000:4741]:443>
SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/chain.pem
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCompression off
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header always set X-Download-Options "noopen"
    Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
    Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure

    ServerAdmin contact@mydomaine.com
    ServerName mydomaine.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomaine.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/public_html/web/

    <Directory /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/public_html/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            SetHandler php7-fcgi-www.mydomaine.com
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www.mydomaine.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I installed NodeJS on my server with the following command :

```
# curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
# apt-get update
# apt-get install nodejs
```

And on Drupal 8 with the following command :

```
# cd /home/www.mydomaine.com/public_html
# npm install drupal-node.j
# npm install pm2 -g
```

Here is the NodeJS configuration for Drupal :

```
# cd node_modules/drupal-node.js
# cp nodejs.config.js.example nodejs.config.js
# nano nodejs.config.js
```

And :

```
settings = {
  scheme: 'http',
  port: 8080,
  host: 'localhost',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: 'hgfjkliutfh',
  backend: {
    port: 443,
    host: 'www.mydomaine.com',
    scheme: 'https',
    basePath: '/web',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  debug: true,
  sslKeyPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/privkey.pem',
  sslCertPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/cert.pem',
  sslCAPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomaine.com/chain.pem',
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  extensions: [],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: false,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: false,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};
```

I added to iptables :

```
# NODE JS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

On my site the following error is displayed in the console :

> Failed to load for  element whose source is «
>   http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js ».

And :

> Refused to load the script
>   'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: data:
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not
>   explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: The ports thing is that processes that are not started by root cannot bind ports < 1024.  If you need to provide SSL (default port 443), you will have to get around that.  Easiest is to get your unix admin to setup a sudo on apachectl.  This way your apache will start as root.  In  your httpd.conf, make sure you set User and Group to your apache user.  This way only the 1st process will be root, others will be  apache user.

Comment: Note: if you WANT port 8080, you will have to change your VirtualHost and Listen to open that port.  But then, if you redirect to 443, port 443 will not be in listen, so that will not help...  You have to setup that root thing.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187726/how-do-daemons-like-apache-or-bind-open-ports-below-1024 and many others on Google for other methods than sudo to do this.

Comment: @Nic3500 I have updated my question, I do not even know if the problem comes from the port